# Theme folder name changed after update theme

Tags: theme-development, themes, updates

For my block theme I use a script from Misha (https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/theme-updates-from-custom-server.html) to update my theme. Everything works fine, only I find out that the theme folder name changes every time.

I use a custom block theme, but have a problem with the folder renaming itself. Example: theme folder name is "**block-theme**".

But after the update it provides a kind of hash, then it is called "**block-theme-hzl6AS**". And then after another update it has a different name, for example "**block-theme-RUs5f7h**".

Function to add inside the "site_transient_update_themes" filter:

```
// let's get the theme directory name
$stylesheet = get_template();

// now let's get the theme version
// but maybe it is better to hardcode it in a constant
$theme = wp_get_theme();
$version = $theme->get('Version');

// connect to a remote server where the update information is stored
$remote = wp_remote_get(
  'https://linktomycustomdomain.nl/info.json',
  array(
    'timeout' => 10,
    'headers' => array(
      'Accept' => 'application/json'
    )
  )
);

// do nothing if errors
if (
  is_wp_error($remote)
  || 200 !== wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($remote)
  || empty(wp_remote_retrieve_body($remote))
) {
  return $transient;
}

// encode the response body
$remote = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($remote));

if (!$remote) {
  return $transient; // who knows, maybe JSON is not valid
}

$data = array(
  'theme' => $stylesheet,
  'url' => $remote->details_url,
  'requires' => $remote->requires,
  'requires_php' => $remote->requires_php,
  'new_version' => $remote->version,
  'package' => $remote->download_url,
);

if ($transient !== false) {
  // check all the versions now
  if (
    $remote
    && version_compare($version, $remote->version, '<')
    && version_compare($remote->requires, get_bloginfo('version'), '<')
    && version_compare($remote->requires_php, PHP_VERSION, '<')
  ) {

      $transient->response[$stylesheet] = $data;
    } else {

      $transient->no_update[$stylesheet] = $data;
    }
}

return $transient;
```

Is this a kind of hash that WordPress itself adds to the folder structure to avoid duplicate folders?

How can I ensure that this name simply remains "**block-theme**" without values ​​afterwards.

Edit 2023/10/05 17:05

Created a new function with update_themes_{$hostname}(https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/update_themes_hostname/), but the same error. the update is working but the folder name is renamed to a **block-theme-CUSTOMHASH**

```
add_filter('update_themes_customdomain.com', array($this, 'self_update'), 10, 4);
```

```
/**
 * Check for updates to this themes
 *
 * @param array  $update   Array of update data.
 * @param array  $theme_data Array of plugin data.
 * @param string $theme_stylesheet Path to plugin file.
 * @param string $locales    Locale code.
 *
 * @return array|bool Array of update data or false if no update available.
 */
function self_update($update, array $theme_data, string 
  $theme_stylesheet, $locales)
  {
  // only check this plugin
  if ('block-theme' !== $theme_stylesheet) {
    return $update;
  }

  // already completed update check elsewhere
  if (!empty($update)) {
    return $update;
  }

  // let's go get the latest version number from GitHub
  $response = wp_remote_get(
    'https://customdomain.com/info.json',
    array(
        'timeout' => 10,
        'headers' => array(
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        )
    )
  );
  
  if (is_wp_error($response)) {
    return;
  } else {
    $output = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response), true);
  }
  
  $new_version_number  = $output['version'];
  $is_update_available = version_compare($theme_data['Version'], 
  $new_version_number, '<');
  
  if (!$is_update_available) {
    return false;
  }
  
  $new_url          = $output['details_url'];
  $new_package      = $output['download_url'];
  $new_requires     = $output['requires'];
  $new_requires_php = $output['requires_php'];

  error_log('$theme_data: ' . print_r($theme_data, true));
  error_log('$new_version_number: ' . $new_version_number);
  error_log('$new_url: ' . $new_url);
  error_log('$new_package: ' . $new_package);

  return array(
    'theme'        => $theme_stylesheet,
    'url'          => $new_url,
    'requires'     => $new_requires,
    'requires_php' => $new_requires_php,
    'new_version'  => $new_version_number,
    'package'      => $new_package,
  );
}
```

Comment: it looks like the authors of those articles and that code are completely unaware of the Update URI API that was introduced in newer versions of WordPress. I would be highly sceptical of that script and consider moving away from it, especially if you plan to use modern WordPress features such as block themes. There are better ways to do this

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks for your comment. Do you have an example for a better way?

Comment: Here's a good place to start: [Introducing `Update URI` Theme Header](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/10/06/introducing-update-uri-theme-header-in-wordpress-6-1/)

Comment: @PatJ This is correct, I applied this in my question (edit), but still a hash after the theme folder name